# mysql getting getting next and previous rows

Tags: mysql

This is an example query I got off of stack overflow. I understand how it works, but if `id` is the primary key isn't the whole `order by id desc/asc` useless? I mean `id<4` isn't going to return a higher key is it? And doesn't the whole `order by` just slow up the query?

```
select * from table where id=4 limit 1
union all
(select * from table where id<4 order by id desc limit 1)
union all
(select * from table where id>4 order by id asc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Tables have no default order.

You might notice that in MySQL/InnoDB if `ID` is your primary key the following two queries will return the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>4 LIMIT 1
```

because in MySQL/InnoDB records are usually ordered by the primary key: but **this is not documented and there are no guarantees that you will always get the next record**. The following two queries are different also in MySQL/InnoDB:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id<4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id<4 LIMIT 1
```

if id=3 is present in your table, the first query will return that row, while the second could return id=3 but it will (probably, **it is not guaranteed**) return the row with the least ID, for example id=1.

As a general rule, you always need to use an `ORDER BY` clause when you are using a `LIMIT` in your query, otherwise the resulting rows could be undetermined.

Answer (score 0):

Being `primary key` only, doesn't garantee that removing `order by` will give the same result. But if `id` is `auto incremented`, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Well,

In the second select, its order the Id's smaller than `4` by `DESCENDING` from top to down.

In the third select, its ordering the Id's larger than `4` by `ASCENDING` order.

I suppose the reason for this is because he want the Id nr `4` first, then the first lower value than `4` then the highest value over `4` .

So the result he wants here is `4,lower than 4,higher than 5`. If this is the right way to achieve this can be discussed.

It wont slow down the query notably, its getting 3 records in total and ordering by a PK is very effective.

The `ORDER BY` is there since `< 4` will usually select the first id in `ASC` order.

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE `id` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Add 6 Rows.

```
INSERT INTO `id` (`Id`) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO `id` (`Id`) VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO `id` (`Id`) VALUES ('4');
INSERT INTO `id` (`Id`) VALUES ('5');
INSERT INTO `id` (`Id`) VALUES ('6');
```

Run this

```
SELECT * FROM id WHERE Id < 5 LIMIT 1;
```

Without the `ORDER BY`, id 1 is selected. So  while "But a primary key isn't going to be out of order in the table" is true, without the order by `DESC` it will order `ASC`.

Comment: YEs i did, did you even read my answer? Why wouldnt id return a higher id than 4?

Comment: I rhetorically asked if `id<4` was going to return a higher key, because I know it's not but was asking just in case there is something about `order by` that manipulates the results in a way that would over ride that.. my question is, what is the point of using `order by` in this example as it seems pointless.

Comment: Its not gonna return a higher key, but with the order by it will gives the previous record. This is used for paging probably.

Comment: again, what's the point of order by, it will return the previous record regardless...

Comment: The order by ensures that its the previous. Lower than 4 can be -1,0,1,2,3. This ensures that its 3.

Comment: But a primary key isn't going to be out of order in the table. I guess they are just using it as a fail safe in case the column they're checking against isn't in order.

Comment: Yes but the order by is ASC by default. When using `LIMIT` the `ORDER BY` is often needed